# Accessing Form Data Immediately On Client Node

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, mean

Is there a way to access submitted form data right away on the client side without having to pass it back from the server? Here is my process:

```
1) Form data is sent over to server
2) Form data is pulled down in params
3) Form data is stored as JSON in a route
4) Form data is accessed by an Ajax call on the client side
```

There's got to be a better way to do this....right?

Comment: You can get your form data with javascript / jQuery  anytime you want.

Comment: Would need to see your form html code (just the form and maybe one input) and any JavaScript on the client that you use to process it. Shouldn't be difficult, but updating your question with some sample code will help.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do it. You can use jQuery, AngularJS, or DOM. You can even use Express to return the data sent in the request, back in the response: `res.json(req.body)`.

Using plain old JavaScript/DOM on the client, do the following for each input element you want to access:

```
// 1. Give the element an id.
<input id="myElementId">

// 2. Reference the input element by its id.
var element = document.getElementById('myElementId');

// 3. Use the reference to get or set the input element's value.
console.log(element.value);
element.value = 'foo';
```